# DataGridview master/detail large tables

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have two tables with a `master-child` relation which have few million records. I'm using a typed dataset generated by visual studio. Since my tables are very large and I don't want to implement Virtual mode, I've modified the master table with a `SELECT TOP X`, to limit the number of rows seen, sorted by internal criteria. Now the problem with the child table is that it still brings the million rows on application startup.

What is the solution of still using the generated `DataSet` and limit the child `DataGridView` from loading all data ? The first solution that comes in my mind is to manually implement the `SqlDataAdapter` data filling for the child rows in an event for row selectin changed in master `DataGridView`. That seems to only load on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no response so far, here is the quickest solution I could find:

1. Keep your current typed dataset and table adapters added
2. Add a FillBY method to your child tableAdapter using the dataset designer. Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
3. Remove from the Form_Load event the call to child tableAdapter Fill() method which was bringing all your database results there
4. Create a handler for [CurrentChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentchanged.aspx) event of your generated bindingSource for the master table and add it in the form Load event.
   Should be something like this:

   this.myMasterTableBindingSource.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(myMasterTableBindingSource_CurrentChanged);
5. Fill your child dataGridView with the info based on the selected item in master table:

   ```
       void myMasterTableBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

           DataRowView selectedRow = myMasterTableBindingSource.Current as DataRowView;
           if (selectedRow != null && !selectedRow.IsNew)
           { 
               this.myChildTableTableAdapter.FillByUser(this.myDataSet.MyChildTable, (int)selectedRow["UserID"]);
           }

   }
   ```